# Why I have value of 0 even i didn't put any values?

Tags: php, sql

I have a form

On my column structure on db I set my **total_price** to `decimal(5,2)`
then i have this input type

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="property_value">
<?php echo render_input('total_price','total_price',isset($project) ? $project->total_price  : '','number'); ?>
</div>
```

my model

```
public function add($data)
{
    $_data['data'] = $data;
    $_data['id']   = $id;
    $_data = do_action('before_update_project', $_data);
    $data = $_data['data'];

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tblprojects', $data);

}
```

then I click save

The question is, why my data that is sent to the db is **0**? Even if I didn't put any value?

Comment: May be its default value is 0

Comment: There’s a few details missing here, such as what does the form look like where the data is input? Before it goes into the DB, what does `$data` look like – maybe output it before the update line?

Answer (score 6):

MySQL columns that are numbers of some-sort often default to `0`. `''` would be an empty string, and (often) numbers are not strings.

If you prefer, you could make the column `nullable`, and then set the default to `NULL`.